# collection_select not saving/erroring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections

I'm trying to create a new course create form with a drop down to select a teach from the teacher's table.

When I put the below in my new course form view I get this error:

> You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!

```
<%= collection_select(:Teacher, :id, @teachers, :id, :name, options = {:prompt => "Select a Teacher"}) %>
```

if I put

```
<%= collection_select(:Teacher, :id, Teacher.find(:all), :id, :name, options = {:prompt => "Select a Teacher"}) %>
```

it creates the form with the correct drop down info but then it won't save.

My course controller create method looks like this

```
 def create
@course = Course.new(params[:course])

respond_to do |format|
  if @course.save
    format.html { redirect_to(@course, :notice => 'Course was successfully created.') }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @course, :status => :created, :location => @course }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @course.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite new action like this

```
    def new
         @course = Course.new
         @teachers = Teachers.all

         respond_to do |format|
           format.html # new.html.erb
           format.xml  { render :xml => @course }
         end
      end
```

After that

```
<%= collection_select(:Teacher, :id, @teachers, :id, :name, options = {:prompt => "Select a Teacher"}) %>
```

should work

Comment: Thanks! that worked. Is that because I need to pull in the "Teachers.all" into the @teachers, otherwise it has nothing to grab? Weird because it listed the teachers in the drop down menu, just didn't save.